# User required to pay for app- upgrade.. why?

Tags: blackberry

We have uploaded an application with paid version (1.0) earlier. Now we uploaded new paid version with some changes & bug-fixes and rolled-out new version (1.1) and uploaded to App-world.

Now since, its just an upgrade, user must be able to upgrade his app for free. (that's understood and common across all other mobile platforms)

But we have received queries from users with regards to new version. User (when trying to upgrade the same app) was asked to pay for app-upgrade. I am confused how can this happen.?

Have i missed something while uploading new version at Blackberry App-world ? please help. I need to resolve this issue. Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might have accidentally specified an **Upgrade Price** when you submitted the new version.  That is separate from the **Price** of the initial release.  This is stated in the [documentation](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/40036/1278467.jsp):

> If you are adding a release that is not the initial release for a
>   product, in the **Upgrade Price** drop-down list, click the price
>   that you want to charge users to upgrade to the latest release of
>   the product.